# BluetoothGatt not discoverservices() onConnectionStateChange in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to discovered ble 4.0 services.Sometimes it discovered some times not discovered. after connection (you are connectiong as gatt-client to device as gatt-server) you should call Discovery device's services. After that device can send you onCharacteristicChanged in case of some changes happened. but its not discovered the services getting following error:

```
  07-02 16:15:19.363 5469-5495/? W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback
                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.discoverServices()' on a null object reference
                                                        at com.actofit.wear.Home.LifeLogStopService$1.onConnectionStateChange(LifeLogStopService.java:103)
                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:181)
                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```